# Making OneDrive folder available offline

Tags: windows, onedrive, windows-10-preview

I'm running the latest version of the Windows 10 Preview Technical. (Build 9879)
and I've tried to figure how to make folder inside the OneDrive available offline.
In windows 8.1 I just right click on file and/or folder and I had that option.
But in windows 10 seems like it doesn't.

Comment: This feature hasn't been enabled yet.  Based on reports it should be coming soon.

Comment: Go to http://insider.windows.com -- download the latest version (build 10074) -- OneDrive appears like another directory on your PC.  works offline

Answer (score 1):

The option is still there. To sync your files from OneDrive to your Windows 10 PC, you have to set up one drive and choose what will be downloaded on your PC.

Press the Windows Key and Type OneDrive and hit enter. Keep the folder opened.

Read a detailed guide on [choose which files and folders will be synced between your PC and OneDrive](http://www.craxworld.com/select-onedrive-folders-files-sync-10329/).

After completing steps restart your PC. It will take some time to start downloading files. You will be able to access them offline.